# can i use use one ajax call instead of two ? mvc4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

i am looking to minimise my code .

I trying to load a Datatable based on dropdown change . so i used two ajax calls to do my work once on initial page load and later on dropdown change .

Can things make simpler

MY CODE :

```
var reason = $("#DropDown_Select").val()

"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                debugger;
                $('#DropDown_Select').change(function () {
                    alert($(this).val());
                    reason = $(this).val()
                    $.ajax({
                        "type": "GET",
                        "dataType": 'json',
                        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "url": sSource+"/"+reason,
                        "data": aoData,
                        "success": function (data) {
                            debugger;
                            fnCallback(data);
                        }
                    });


                });
                $.ajax({
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "url": sSource +"/"+reason,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        fnCallback(data);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Is code minimization possible in my above case ?

Regards

Comment: From my experience, DataTables automatically triggers a call after being initialized. Unless that is not the case anymore (new version, etc), there's no need for the second ajax call in your example. Also, just a tip, if you're using a specific plugin, might want to mention/tag that :) DataTables is well-known, but it's generally a good idea :)

Comment: ok fine mate ty for nice advice :) cheers . I am using jquery 1.11 ,datatable 1.9 with datatable editable . As you worked on datatables i preasume i want to know with respect to my above question is there a way to pass additonal parameter to deleteData method at controller on delete button click . i am trying to send a reason for deleting (entering via prompt) . Normally on delete just id goes to controller . so i am trying to add reason parameter

Comment: It's possible, I did something similar in the past. I lack the time to help you (it's been a while), unfortunately, but the DataTables documentation on the site explains everything you need to get it working.

Comment: yeah ty . i will get going now i am trying via query strings to pass it through controller . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your AJAX calls are identical, you can just put that part of the code in a function, with the needed values as parameters:

```
function handleChange(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, reason) {
  $.ajax({
    "type": "GET",
    "dataType": 'json',
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "url": sSource+"/"+reason,
    "data": aoData,
    "success": function (data) {
      fnCallback(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Then use the function:

```
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

  $('#DropDown_Select').change(function () {
    handleChange(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, $(this).val());
  });

  handleChange(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, $("#DropDown_Select").val());

}
```

Comment: sSource undefined on my initial load? i guess some minor issue above

Comment: @supercool: Aha, that is a parameter to the function, so it's local to the calling code. Just add it as a parameter. I updated the code above.

Comment: mate i guess now aoData will be undefined because it is not defined .! so we have to pass all ha ? sSource, aoData, fnCallback